# Reminder being executed only when adding new reminder

Tags: windows-phone-7

i am trying to use the reminder api but with no luck. The code that i use to create the reminder is located below. The thing that happens is that the reminder is not triggered until i add another reminder, att this point the old reminder goes of immediately. I guess this code does not say much as it is almost copy pasted from Microsoft's tutorial on reminders. however i do not know where the problem could be otherwise (i will post other code snippets if you have suggestions where the problem may lie)

```
Reminder notification = new Reminder(""+uniqueId);
            notification.Title = "Title";
            notification.Content = "Content";
            notification.BeginTime = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(10);
            notification.RecurrenceType = RecurrenceInterval.None;
            notification.NavigationUri = new Uri("/MyPage.xaml?id=" + uniqueId, UriKind.Relative);

            // Register the reminder with the system.
            ScheduledActionService.Add(notification);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok there was nothing wrong with the code. The emulators system time was set to automatic but was somehow going 20 min wrong which led to strange behaviour. After setting time manually it works as expected.